# Online offline user staus in quickblox

Tags: ios, quickblox

I am referring to the sample iOS app in quickblox to integrate the chat / call feature in my app. But I see there is a difference in framework in the SDK and Q-municate app.

Video / audio call works fine with the sample app given along with [SDK](http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS)  but when I tried to find online / offline status of the user i had to include framework from [Q-municate](http://quickblox.com/developers/Q-municate). After including that i am not able to run on simulator , it gives error

> "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64"

but it runs on real device.

The video call hangs on device with framework from Q-municate but works fine with the framework in SDK.

Any idea what is the difference ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update: Following method should still work. There is also a new way to do this, which was not available at the time this answer was posted. See Update-2 section below.**

To find the status of the user (online/offline), Quickblox suggests the following:

Each user has the `lastRequestAt` field - that shows last user activity time. You can use it to determine if user online or offline now.

```
NSInteger currentTimeInterval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
NSInteger userLastRequestAtTimeInterval   = [[user lastRequestAt] timeIntervalSince1970];

// if user didn't do anything last 5 minutes (5*60 seconds)    
if((currentTimeInterval - userLastRequestAtTimeInterval) > 5*60){ 
     // user is offline now
}
```

**Update-2**

To find the list of online users use the following:

```
NSMutableDictionary *filters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
filters[@"filter[]"] = @"date last_request_at gt 2012-03-20T08:47:34Z";

[QBRequest usersWithExtendedRequest:filters page:[QBGeneralResponsePage responsePageWithCurrentPage:1 perPage:100] successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBGeneralResponsePage *page, NSArray *users) {
     // Request succeeded   
} errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
     // Handle error  
}];
```

Taken from [here.](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-users-ios#Online.5COffline_status)

Comment: the solution is not that reliable since its purely depending on the timing and not the real time status.

Comment: `lastRequestAt` is always `nil`

Comment: i get this time only when user login or logout not when messages is sent or recived [user lastRequestAt] can u help me out of this

Comment: @FeminaBrahmbhatt not sure what you are looking for, can you detail what issue you are facing, will be happy to help.

Comment: check this ans - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58235163/7301439